# Can not read utmpx file in go

Tags: c, macos, unix, go

```
package main

import (
 "os"
 "fmt"
)

func main() {
  fd, err := os.Open("/var/run/utmpx")
  fmt.Println(fd, err)
  var data []byte
  len, err := fd.Read(data)
  fmt.Println(len, err)
}
```

> &{0xc42000a240} nil
>
> 0 nil

There is no error, also no data.

This path `/var/run/utmpx` is read from system header file.

How to get this path is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44036358/5819540)

system: macOS el capiton, go version go1.8 darwin/amd64

**My final goal is to read this file into go struct.**This file contains system users infomation.

**Can I do that ?** I will keep trying...

Comment: are you running the script with administrator privileges?

Comment: @mic4ael Hi, I'm using macOS, I run this with `go run main.go`, how can I run this with root ?

Comment: `sudo go run main.go`

Comment: `data` has a length of 0 (it's nil), so you're trying to read 0 bytes.

Comment: @mic4ael go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/local/go
got this error

Comment: @JimB Yes, it shouldn't be 0 bytes.How can I read this file...

Comment: @JimB you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ioutil.ReadFile` function for this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    fd, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/var/run/utmpx")
    fmt.Println(string(fd), err)
}
```

The problem in your original code is that you read into `data` that is 0 bytes long. Since the reader interface reads only reads up to `len(data)`, it reads nothing. More on that: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader