# How to cast bytes to struct(c struct) in go?

Tags: c, unix, go

```
package main

/*
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <utmpx.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *path_utmpx = _PATH_UTMPX;

typedef struct utmpx utmpx;
*/
import "C"
import (
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
)

type Record C.utmpx

func main() {

  path := C.GoString(C.path_utmpx)

  content, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
  handleError(err)

  var records []Record

  // now we have the bytes(content), the struct(Record/C.utmpx)
  // how can I cast bytes to struct ?
}

func handleError(err error) {
  if err != nil {
    panic("bad")
  }
}
```

I'm trying to read `content` into `Record` 
I have asked a few related questions.

[Cannot access c variables in cgo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44036358/5819540)

[Can not read utmpx file in go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45300938/5819540)

I have read some articles and posts but still cannot figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. If you were wanting to use the C library, you would use the C library to read the file.

Don't use cgo purely to have struct definitions, you should create these in Go yourself. You could then write the appropriate marshal / unmarshal code to read from the raw bytes.

A quick Google shows that someone has already done the work required to convert a look of the relevant C library to Go. See the [utmp repository](https://github.com/ericlagergren/go-gnulib/tree/master/utmp).

A short example of how this could be used is:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ericlagergren/go-gnulib/utmp"
)

func handleError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func byteToStr(b []byte) string {
    i := bytes.IndexByte(b, 0)
    if i == -1 {
        i = len(b)
    }
    return string(b[:i])
}

func main() {
    list, err := utmp.ReadUtmp(utmp.UtmpxFile, 0)
    handleError(err)
    for _, u := range list {
        fmt.Println(byteToStr(u.User[:]))
    }
}
```

You can view the [GoDoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/ericlagergren/go-gnulib/utmp) for the `utmp` package for more information.

Comment: I know this repo and I have read it. I just want to try out. Thanks for your answer. I got `undefined: utmp.ReadUtmp`, `undefined: utmp.UtmpxFile`.

Comment: I want to wait to see is there other answer.

Comment: GZ Xue, did you run `go get github.com/ericlagergren/go-gnulib/utmp` to install the utmp library?

Comment: yes, but I got `package github.com/ericlagergren/go-gnulib: no buildable Go source files in /Users/xxx/code/src/github.com/ericlagergren/go-gnulib` @Mark

Comment: As Mark says, you need to run `go get github.com/ericlagergren/go-gnulib/utmp`. You need the `utmp` at the end. Alternatively, if easier, install the [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) tool and run `dep init` in your project to automatically install the package.